# Offset text in HTML Select Option List

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, html-select

Can't work out why the following is happening in a selection list:

```html
<body>
  <select>
    <option value="This">This</option>
    <option value="That">That</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

After loading the window (in Chrome) the following is displayed:

[image]

But if I change the size of the window is displays correctly:

[image]

Is there a way of setting the position of the options?

EDIT TO ANSWER:
After a lot of annoyance, it turns out this appears to be from the monitors (I assume the drivers) that I have connected to the computer (does not happen with the monitor at work). Interestingly it also does not happen in IE on either system.

Comment: In your demo above it works fine. I've never seen this behaviour before. Have you got some CSS you haven't shown us?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing anything else that is going on with the page.

Comment: No CSS on this one.

Comment: @gazza something else has to be included with the page. Is there libraries you are using? We need to see code that reproduces this error for us to help you.

Comment: This is just test code and it's still happening ... I am running it through Google scripts with the following code <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <select >
        <option value="This">This</option>
        <option value="That">That</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Check if you have zoom level over 100% in Chrome

Comment: The only other code is to setup the display: // ******************** SETUP THE DISPLAY ********************
function doGet(e) { // MAIN SCREEN
  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('Filename')
  .evaluate()}

Comment: No zoom is spot on 100%

Comment: Put code in question, not in comments. It is impossible to read easily in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Your `viewport` meta in html will be ignored. You need to set it [explicitly](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addMetaTag(String,String))

Comment: Had a user at work report this problem in one of our web apps yesterday.  Just like you, any small adjustment to the size of the Chrome browser window  would trigger the select list to re-render properly.  Were you able to pinpoint a specific problem with your monitor or drivers that resolved it?  It sounds an awful lot like a scaling calculation problem, either with Windows or Chrome.  I'll be troubleshooting today, and will post back with whatever clues I find.